# input field not updating to sql

Tags: php, html, sql

Can anyone help me out, not the expert on php/sql. Have looked about but can't find my answer to my problem. My logged in user has an inout field which they put in their answer. On the submit button I want it to update to the sql the users answer. But nothing happens

I have an input field which is this.

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="post">

           <div class="form-group">

                <input type="text" name="answer" placeholder="Answer" class="form-control" value="<?php ($_POST['answer']); ?>" />

               <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />



            </div>
        </form>
```

And my php which is this.

```
function post_answer() {

        $answer = $_POST['answer'];

        $sql = "UPDATE users SET answer = '".$answer."' WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."'";


}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're making an assumption the query is working but you never execute it in any way.

Comment: Thanks Jay, can you elaborate on what I need to do. I am a novice on all this.

Comment: I would suggest that you work through some basic PHP / MySQL tutorials. This is pretty much PHP/MySQL101

Comment: What you have done is created a string of letters ($sql) that happens to be a mysql query. To actually use that query, you need to create a connection to the db, and execute the query.

Comment: while at it, could you correct the title of your topic?

Comment: I suggest watching this to learn how to get it to work: [link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWHkDwEoZ29Q9FKtWVjA46HC)